# how to disable or override the fonts inherited from svg in the web pages by default

Tags: css, svg, highcharts, fonts

I faced this issue when I needed to change the data label of high chart charts.

fiddle link: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/surajcs009/43wjn4f4/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 'DivisionA',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 1
        }, {
            name: 'DivisionB',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'DivisionC',
            value: 4,
            colorValue: 3
        }, {
            name: 'DivisionD',
            value: 3,
            colorValue: 4
        }, {
            name: 'DivisionE',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 5
        }, {
            name: 'DivisionF',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 6
        }, {
            name: 'DivisionG',
            value: 1,
            colorValue: 7
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

If one uses chrome, try to inspect the data label e.g. DivisionA, you will find that it's font has been inherited from svg. I tried to change the font and apply css using `.highcharts-container {.. },` but it's not working.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the `text` element (the parent of `tspan`) instead. So you can try this :

```
.highcharts-label text {
    font-family: ...;
}
```

Comment: Hi Afif, Is there any way, we can change font style of all the components of high chart, instead of writing the css individually for label, axis, legend-series etc.

Comment: @SKumar yes you can simply target all `text` by using for example `svg text { }`

Comment: Yes, it worked for all the default svg values, simple but elegant answer, thanks.